# How to Implement Cascading in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a following tables in database

> people{id,name,email}
>   delegates{id,people_id,company}
>   and I have two model classes
>   Person
>   Delegate

I want to establish relation between Person and Delegate, means how to cascade save operation when I call on delegate.

And I want to write a controller that should display a form to add a delegate. How to do that please explain me with syntax?

Answer (score 1):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1036/delete notice the second param